# Access err 2004 - out of memory

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have several clients that I make databases for, all are pretty similar... They all have a screen with current data displayed.  This screen/pc combo also sends some emails, uploads data, etc... usually without problems... however, one client keeps getting an 2004 (Not enough memory) and 3035 (system resources exceeded).  I have tracked the memory usage on the device and it hasn't gone about 50%.  I ran a memory test and no errors were found.

Today, I notice the error and was able to try a few things.  With Access open, I could not open or design view any forms.  Some queries I could get to open to SQL, but not design view.  Crosstab queries would not open in design or SQL.  Neither would open and show any data.

These errors are usually logged, and I will get several 2004s in a row, then it will switch to several 3035s, then eventually it will just quit altogether.  Closing Access and reopening will always fix it (for a while).

I have decompiled and recompiled.  I have tried accdb and accde versions.  This is Access 2007.  What should I try next?

Comment: I'd ask the client to try it on a different PC, they may need a clean up / reinstall of windows / new PC. I was in this situation just the other day - they hadn't modified windows since their first installation of Win 7 and the PC could barely run a web browser, let alone a macro enabled spreadsheet. Computers collect a lot of junk, they need maintainance, just like cars do.

Comment: @Absinthe - thanks!  I think that is my best bet.  I thought about replacing the RAM, but I don't know if that will do anything for me either.  It is a Windows 10 PC, and does not have access to the internet, so it should be okay (junk wise) but this sounds like it may be the simplest first step.

Comment: Okay - so I decided to give it a quick test on another computer... didn't make it 12 hours without the error showing up.  What now?  It seems like I should get a different error if there was some sort of corrupt query or form.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: Try a compact and repair and post any code here or on CodeReview you think might be responsible. Are your databases as normalized as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can't add as comment, but one thing to try would be to check the service pack level for Access, the latest for Office 2007 is SP3.

Also, if the issue is with multiple forms, then it could indicate database corruption rather than issues with individual forms.  Have you tried to import all objects into a brand new container and run it from that?

Comment: I rebuilt from scratch the two different forms that are open when the corruption happens.  At first, I removed them and the database worked fine, so now that they have been re-created without copying anything from the originals, I will see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: A good alternative to rebuilding the forms from scratch is to use the *undocumented* Application.SaveAsText and Application.LoadFromText commands.  These output the form as a raw VB text file (which you can save as a text file to your computer), and then you can delete the forms from the database, and then reload them from the text file.  It's a technique I've used often to fix some weird corruption issue on forms - doesn't work *every* time, but works more often than not in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the SaveAsText comment.  I had read about doing that, but couldn't figure out how - I tried to export a form as text, but that isn't even close.  I will give this a try in the future.  The rebuilt forms seem to be working for now.